# Sharding on MySQL vs PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql, sharding, distributed-system

It seems like most large companies that have to shard their databases choose MySQL over PostgreSQL. What are the major advantages that MySQL has over PostgreSQL when it comes to distributed database? I don't see any major downside to Postgres that will prevent a successful implementation of sharding at the application level, but the sheer number of companies that choose MySQL over Postgres is giving me pause and making me wonder if I'm missing something.

Comment: what do you mean with `Sharding` ? i assume you mean horizontal partition of data in a database here? If that the case look into the way how you need to make partitions on PostgreSQL and compare that with MySQL then you would notice the MySQL syntax is much more clear and clean... PostgreSQL 11 improved the partitions syntax alot but still

Comment: More companies choose MySQL over PostgreSQL, regardless of whether they are going do implement sharding or not. MySQL is simply way more popular than PostgreSQL. For example, see https://db-engines.com/en/ranking

Comment: That's not a comment about the merit of MySQL vs. PostgreSQL, it's just a fact about market share of the two products. I've said in the past that PostgreSQL hurt its own momentum many years ago when they neglected Windows users. MySQL leaped ahead in popularity after that, and even though PostgreSQL later produced a native Windows build, it never fully recovered in popularity.

Comment: The popularity of a software is not always the best measure for its quality. See Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

`PARTITIONing` involves a single server; Sharding involves many servers.  They solve (or fail to solve) different problems.  Partitioning provides very few use cases to justify its existence; sharding provides *write* scaling at the cost of complexity.

MySQL's has no built-in sharding capability.  There are 3rd party packages that assist with such, but there is still a large burden on the DBA.  (See Spider and various Proxy servers.)

So, I see no reason why Postgres (or any other RDBMS) could not be sharded.  After all, *you* do most of the work; the RDBMS sits on multiple machines not realizing that there are siblings with other chunks of the data.

(Disclaimer:  I am very familiar with MySQL, and not familiar with Postgres.)